# Can i get the Lead ID once it has already been converted?

Tags: reporting, salesforce-id, leads, lead-conversion, conversion

My BI colleague asked me to put if I can 2 new fields on account, both related with the lead that this account was before conversion. One is the Creation Date and the other is the ID of the lead.

I already managed to do this creating new fields on both lead and Account and customizing the Mapping on conversion from lead to account.

But this only modify obviously all the new leads that are being converted.

Is there a way to obtain this 2 attributes for all the already converted leads?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a standard report type of '**Leads with converted lead information**'.

Add a filter of **Converted = true**

This will give you all your converted leads, the contact, opportunity, and account they are related to, and the lead Id as well

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking of using this fields on a Dynamic Dashboard, so can i access to this fields on an apex controller ?

Comment: Ok, stupid question by my side, i can easily retrieve that by an SOQL call. 

Thanks.

Comment: No worries, yes there is a field on the lead called ConvertedAccountID, so your SOQL would be something like `Select Id, Name, ConvertedAccountId From Lead Where IsConverted = True`

Comment: I finally came up with this solution. Wich was the one who benefit more the interest of my Collegue, i created both fields as i described i did before and created a Batchable that updates the fields for all the old records that didnt have already this fields filled.  
This way they will be easier to access on the Dynamic Dashboards and also can be useful to have this values arround when doing reports and other stuff.